# How To Select The First line or (first 20 Characters) of a pragraph using Microsoft Office Interop word.?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I have been trying the following code to get the first line or first 20 characters of a paragraph using Microsoft office interop word 12

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application w = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
    int iParaStart = Para.Range.Start;
    Para.Range.Text = "A big Paragraph Comes here …….";
    Para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
    int iParaEnd = Para.Range.End; 
  // to select the first sentance code tried       
  doc.Range(iRangeStart,iRangeEnd).Sentences.First.Select();
doc.Range(iRangeStart,iRangeEnd).Sentences.First.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor=WdColor.wdColorOrange;
 // to get the characters code tried
 doc.Range(iRangeStart,iRangeStart+20).Select();
```

It seems like not working How can i do this . I need to select the either first sentence or first 20 characters

Comment: If you're using this code in a long running application or working with many files, this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752) will help with hanging Office processes (Same issues applies to Word as to Excel)

Comment: First off all thank you for the reply, and I am sorry because  I am not an expert to go that much deep. I am not dealing with hanging office process now . Just trying to select the first sentence or first 20 char of a paragraph..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using (i assumed you have properly open application and word document):

```
// get paragraph range
paragraphs = doc.Paragraphs;
Word.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphs.First;
Word.Range paragraphRange = paragraph.Range;
```

Selecting first sentence:

```
Word.Sentences sentences = paragraphRange.Sentences;
Word.Range firstSentence = sentences.First;
firstSentence.Select();
```

Selecting first 20 characters:

```
if (paragraphRange.Text.Length > 20)
{
    Word.Range range = paragraph.Range.Duplicate;
    range.SetRange(range.Start, range.Start + 20);
    range.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

... and given a [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.document_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instance:

```
var wordApplication = new Application();
var myDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\...\my.docx");
```

... you can select the first 20 chars of a paragraph like this:

```
var substring = myDocument.Paragraphs.First.Range.Text.Substring(0, 20);
```

... and you can select the first line like this:

```
var firstLine = myDocument.Paragraphs.First.Range.Sentences.First.Text;
```

References:

- [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.range%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Sentences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.sentences%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Paragraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.paragraphs%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the Answer and i have got the answer from the previous post and I tried your code also it also works.